# Resize grid with images vertical - android

Tags: android, layout, resize

I need images have the container size "GridLayout" according to the size.

Just catch their horizontal size, but I also need the vertical.

What am I missing? thanks

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/fondo_01">


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:useDefaultMargins="false"
    android:background="@drawable/corners_main_layout"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_white"
    tools:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_white"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:columnCount="3">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_skinav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idskinav" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/skinav"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_social"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idsocial" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/social"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idstats" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stats"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_alerts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idalerts" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alerts"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idinbox" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inbox"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/idinfo" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/info"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Is there another easier way to do it? I tried with the new ConstraintLayout but I have not succeeded.

------UPDATE----

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Square Image View for proper sizing of your Grid Items.

Create a separate class for defining the size dynamically for your ImageView that should inherit ImageView class as shown below:

```
    public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);

    }
}
```

The setMeasuredDimension(width, width); will automatically set your height as the width.

In xml file use this class as a view in place of ImageView as shown below:

```
<com.packagepath.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/Imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: If the container is a smaller grid , then you have to make a ratio accordingly. The container size which you are giving requires at least 4 in each row so that it looks decent. I myself have faced this type of situations a lot. I hope i have made myself clear.

Comment: Now I have another little problem .....
What alternative is there for android layout_columnWeight = "1"?
API only works with> 21 .... i need> 16

Comment: Did you try removing that statement & give height as wrap content in each of the linear layouts ? I think this will work.

Comment: The linear layout have warp_content..... when remove layout_columWeigth="1" the linear_layout missing :-S

Comment: Oh .. My bad for the above answer. Stupid was that from me. Anyways, I recommend you to make a custom Grid View , in which you can control the width and height and thus you can avoid using the columWeight attribute.

Here is an example :- https://gist.github.com/way2jatin/69fa487014cddfecd0fd266dd6a319fc

Comment: I'm gonna try what you have sent me, but ........
Would not it be solved in a simpler way? I've already gotten to the above what I wanted, and my images are resized perfectly. Only need an alternative the the android: layout_columnWeight = "1" thanks

Comment: I try code but get Error UI build:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123401/discussion-between-jatin-jha-and-daicon).